# displaced texts with inkscape pdf_tex output

Tags: inkscape, latex

I have a canves open Inkscape which looks like the following:

[image]

However when I save it as pdf with the pdf_tex option the result in my latex file looks like:

[image]

Any idea how I can solve it?

The pdf_tex file in addition looks as follows:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{586.11398865bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.85431485)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{./figures/pdf_texs/imped_convex_.pdf}}%
    \put(0.17376914,0.80322859){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Potentialsolutionspace\\Reduced,meaningfulsearchspace\\Skillframework\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.0298576,0.24798999){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\rotatebox{90}{\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Searchspacereduction\end{tabular}}}}}%
    \put(0.15622173,0.67559152){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Allpossiblemotorcontrols\\Adaptiveimpedancecontroller\\Dynamicsystemlimits\\Manipulationand\\interactioncontrol\\andinteractioncontrol\\Partitionedmanipulation\\Skilldesign\\Qualitymetric\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Can you share the .svg file? Probably the problem can be avoided by placing each term in a separate text box.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the origin of this scetch is a pdf file that I removed the other texts around it after importing it in inskape. Perhaps I can separate text boxes in inkscape? I'm not sure how though.

Comment: is there something that maybe decomposes a box into a number of other boxes

Comment: Can you share the .svg file so we can confirm that this is indeed the problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz saved it as svg here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkiChoTr1JeFeFd8s2vpWqGN7cQ?e=JbYsmI

Answer (score 3):

OK, the problem is definitely that the whole text is just in two big text blocks with line breaks

[image]

Even worse, the text does not even have true spaces. I suggest to manually add new text blocks which will only have one expression in them. In addition, select `center align` instead if `left align` for each text block, this will make the resulting image more robust to changes to the font size.

Doing this as an example for two blocks, will result in the following `.pdf_tex` file

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{586.11398772bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.85431482)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{imped_convex_1.pdf}}%
    \put(-0.81669674,-1.58208591){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0.3965047,0.67854242){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{All possible motor controls}}}%
    \put(0.42600661,0.54047367){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{Adaptive impedance controller}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

[image]